# In MySQL, what is the difference between the SOURCE command and \. ?

Tags: mysql

From looking at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-batch-commands.html
I am under the understanding that they can both be used to execute an SQL script, however there are no comments on why there are two methods of doing this, or any differences between the two.

Comment: "source"  designed to run a small number of sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

There is very little difference between the two.

Every MySQL client command (that is, commands which affect the client, rather than normal query verbs like `SELECT` and `UPDATE`) has both a full form (e.g, `SOURCE`, `HELP`, `PAGER`, `QUIT`) and an abbreviated form (e.g, `\.`, `\h`, `\P`, `\q`). They are generally synonymous; the primary difference is that the full forms can only be used at the start of a command, but the abbreviations can be used at any point. For instance:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE GO
```

does not work, but

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE \g
```

does. This is only really relevant to `\g` and `\G`, though; most other commands would not make sense to use in this way.

Comment: OK, I see why no information mentions this subtle difference.

Comment: My 2 cents: Pay attention to omitting semicolon as in @duskwuff's \g example. It goes either like "mysql> source filename.sql;" or "mysql> \. filename.sql". If you add a semicolon in latter, mysql thinks it's part of file's name